# How to define foreign key relationships in sails with mysql

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I'm really new to sails and all of the documentation to do with ORM is about as basic as you could get, so I'm struggling to understand how to set up relationships in my models. Here are my tables and models: http://pastebin.com/yt8jFTkk

Now, what I'm trying to do is something like:

```
AccountApplication.findOne({
    token: 'someTokenHere', 
    application.type: 'foo', 
    application.serviceProvider: 'bar'
}).populate('application')
.populate('account').exec(...)...
```

I would settle for this and manually check for the expected application type and service provider as token overlap seems pretty improbable and use a find() instead of findOne():

```
AccountApplication.findOne({
    token: 'someTokenHere'
}).populate('application')
.populate('account').exec(...)...
```

I guess I'm at a bit of a loss as to how sails / waterline is to know that the the account_id on my AccountApplication model is the foreign key for the account property. What am I missing here? Currently populate() on either account or application are doing nothing using the models above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have duplicate `account` and `accountId` properties that mean the same thing.  What you want is `account: { model: 'account', columnName: 'account_id', type: 'integer', required: true}` and get rid of the `accountId` attribute.

The important thing is that you only have one attribute for the association that stores the underlying data; you don't need to specify the foreign key column additionally.  Apparently there was a bug where specifying `columnName` on an association would break the association, but it seems to have been resolved https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/362.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up stumbling onto this myself the other night.

Comment: The account and accountId properties can't both exist at the same time? But in some scenarios, this is really necessary, how to ?

Comment: @rwing it's probably not a satisfactory answer, but perhaps in that case you may want to use a raw database query.